# Discord Python Bot Add Color to Role

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

to set the color of an existing role?

This is my code that create roles:

```
roles = ["SSS | Weeb", "SS Rang | Weeb", "S Rang | Weeb", "A Rang | Weeb", "B Rang | Weeb",
                 "C Rang | Weeb", "D Rang | Weeb", "E Rang | Weeb", "F Rang | Weeb", "Junior Rang | Weeb"]
        for i in roles:
            seasons = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=str(i))
            if str(seasons) == str(i):
                pass
            else:
                await message.guild.create_role(name=str(i))
```

Now I want there to set sth like

```
roles = ["SSS | Weeb", "SS Rang | Weeb", "S Rang | Weeb", "A Rang | Weeb", "B Rang | Weeb",
                 "C Rang | Weeb", "D Rang | Weeb", "E Rang | Weeb", "F Rang | Weeb", "Junior Rang | Weeb"]
        colors = ["red, green", "blue"] # and much more
        for i in range(len(roles)):
            seasons = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=str(roles[i]))
            if str(seasons) == str(roles[i]):
                pass
            else:
                await message.guild.create_role(name=str(roles[i]))
            ->  await message.guild.add_color_to_role(role_name=str(roles[i]), color=colors[i])
```

I didn't found anything ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as `Guild.add_color_to_role`, it's `Role.edit` and pass the color as a kwargs, also you can pass the color when creating the role:

```py
# Editing the role
await role.edit(colour=discord.Colour.blue())
# Creating a role with the color
await guild.create_role(name="whatever", colour=discord.Colour.blue())
```

You can also pass hex values to the colour kwarg

```py
await guild.create_role(name="whatever", colour=0xff0000) # Red color
```

So, your colour list must be either a list of `discord.Colour` instances or a list of ints

```py
colors = [0xff0000, discord.Colour.blue(), 0x00ff00]
```

To go through both of the list at the same time you can use the `zip` function (Note: both lists should be the same length)

```py
role_names = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
role_colors = [0xff0000, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff] 

for name, color in zip(role_names, role_colors):
    print(f"Name: {name}, color: {color}")

# Name: name1, color: 0xff0000
# Name: name2, color: 0x00ff00
# ...
```

Your code would look something like this

```py
role_names = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
role_colors = [0xff0000, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff] # The default color is 0x000000 (white)

for name, color in zip(role_names, role_colors):
    print(f"Name: {name}, color: {color}") # -> Name: name1, color: 0xff0000 ...

    # Getting the role
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=name)
    # Checking if the role exists (in other words - if the `role` variable is not a NoneType)
    if role is not None: 
        # Role does not exist, create it here
        role = await message.guild.create_role(name=name, colour=color)
```

EDIT

To use colors like `#5482a5`

```py
color = "#5482a5"
color = color[1:] # removing the initial `#`
color = int(color, 16) # pass this as the colour kwarg
```

#### Reference:

- [`Role.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.edit)
- [`Guild.create_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_role)
- [`zip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp)

Comment: Thank you much :) 
Can I also use Colors in this format:
`#5482a5`
?

Comment: Yes! But you have to convert them to an integer with base 16, let me edit the answer

Comment: Trank you so much :)

Comment: By Converting Color get this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '#b1afc8'

Comment: `color = colors[i]
color = color[1:]  # removing the initial `#`
color = int(color, 16)  # pass this as the colour kwarg`

Comment: Well, it works flawlessly for me, you must be doing something incorrectly

Comment: oh sry, I has made a silly mistake, make " #..." with space ... sry, and again so much thanks, i haven't enough points to vote the answer up, but set that it resolved, if i had these points, i will defenetly vote this up

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a colour when you create the role.

```
await message.guild.create_role(name=str(roles[i], colour=discord.Color.blue()))
```

Since you've actually asked for how to edit the colour you can do this:

```
role = await message.guild.create_role(name=str(roles[i]))
await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.orange())
```